# conditional probability simulation in R

Tags: r

Good morning to you

I am in my first steps in generating data simualtion, and i want to implement this situation:

To generate synthetic data having two variables: gender and buy, i suppose that gender follows binomial law with probability 0.5. i want to say to R to simulate the conditional probability : P( buy/ gender is female) = 0.25 and p( buy given that gender is male) = 0.70. so i did the codes using simstudy:

```
 <- defData(varname = "buy", dist = "binary", formula=0.5)
 dt <- genData(20, def)
 defC <- defCondition(condition = "gen == 1", dist = "binary" , formula = 0.25 )
 defC <- defCondition(defC, condition = "gen == 0", dist = "binary" , formula = 0.70)
 dt <- addCondition(defC, dt, "buy")
 dt
```

i tried another solution:

```
 def <- defData(def, varname = "buy", dist = "binary", formula="0.70 -  0.45*(gen == 1)")
 dt <- genData(20, def)
 dt
```

Is there a difference between these two implementations in simulation proccess?  ( since the values are probabilistic i can't be sure of the difference between these two codes just by observing the results). Are they satisfy the goal of simulation (conditional probability)?

Thanks in advance for the help !

an example of what i got:
[[image]]
[image]

Comment: You definitely should be able to compare the outputs. Simulate thousands and run averages of `gen` and the conditional averages of `buy`. They should converge to your bernoulli probabilities. If they don't, something is wrong with your setup. Here's an example that tests normal means:  `N_means <- sapply(1:1000,function(x) mean(rnorm(1000))); plot(density(N_means),main="Distribution of 1000 Means of Standard Normal (N=1000)")` .  This takes a sample of N=1000 from a standard normal, calculates the mean, and then does this another 999 times sticking all the results into an array that you plot.

Comment: Thanks @quickreaction for your reply, i appreciate it. It's not that i can't compare the two pieces of code results. it's not the empirical comparaison that i m interested in. what makes me confused is the logic defferences  behind the two functions (defData only VS defData+defCondition ) of the predefined function in simstudy pachage.I think there should be defferences between them because if the two codes that i wrote are equivalents, why the author programmed two solutions while one is  largely enough!

Comment: Did you confirm that they're different by doing like I suggested? Judging by the looks of the first result, you're not getting a valid output. A lot of people write packages where they've not adhered to software design principles. You should always be checking your assumptions. You can also dive into the man pages or the source code to look at the differences in the implementations. For something this simple, you should probably just write the code yourself.